# Make field editable in List, EditForm?

Tags: 2007, list-definition

[N00b to SP, sorry! Inherited an SP2007 site]

I have a List in SP2007, when I Edit an item, it opens up the EditForm.aspx page, however, some of the fields are not editable.

I now need to make one of the fields editable, but I cannot see where I change this?

Thx

Comment: Which fields you want to edit?

Comment: Can you see the fields and not edit them, or are the fields hidden from the edit page?

Comment: See them but not edit.  Someone mentioned javascript to me?  Is that a way to "readonly" the fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column might be a calculated column or marked hidden in the content type so it isn't available to edit on the EditForm page.  Go into the List settings and check that out to see what the column type is and if it has been hidden.

If it was hidden, you can mark it to optional and it will appear and can be edited.  If it's a calculted column, you can't edit it directly.

The other alternative is to go into datasheet view and edit the item that way.